# Stack android notifications as they come from gcm

Tags: android, notifications, stack, google-cloud-messaging

I have a chat style app. My server is sending a gcm notification when a user receive a message.

Android side I'm listening to these message and I trigger a notification. 
For now I'm calling .notify with the same ID so I don't have multiple notification in the status bar.

What I would like to achieve is something like gmail. It groups all the messages in ONE notification and it can expand.

I had a look around and I saw the inbox style notification, the problem is that I do not understand how to "append"  messages as they come from gcm?

Because everything I build a notification it erase the one already in the bar.

So... I was wondering if I had to to store the notification in the database? And when a message comes i retrieve the previous messages and can fully create the notification?

If I follow the above I will have to listen when a notification gets clicked or cleared.

Is this something that makes sense? Or am I reinventing the wheel and there is already something similar implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're on the right track. Yes, you will need to save the information somewhere so you can do something with it when you get additional push notifications and then you know what your summary content will look like.

Here is an example to read your saved notifications (as JSON), so you can perform grouping:

```
private LinkedList<JSONObject> getPreviousNotifications()
{
    File file = new File( getFilesDir(), NOTIFICATIONS_FILENAME );
    if ( file.exists() )
    {
        LinkedList<JSONObject> list = new LinkedList<>();
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( file ) );
            String line;
            while ( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null )
            {
                list.add( new JSONObject( line ) );
            }
            reader.close();
        }
        catch ( JSONException e )
        {
            Log.debug( "json error" );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            Log.debug( "failed to open file for reading" );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now that you have your previous notifications, you can generate your "Expanded" text and also your Summary text. Loop through your previous (and current) items and generate a couple of lines of content for your Expanded version and also decide what you want to use for the Summary display.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder summary = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this )
         .setSmallIcon(  R.drawable.ic_stat_notify )
         .setColor( getResources().getColor( R.color.push_group_background ) )
         .setContentTitle( yourSummaryTitle )
         .setContentText( yourDetailedTextBuilder.toString() )
         .setDefaults( Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE )
         .setPriority( Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT )
         .setTicker( yourSummaryText )
         .setGroup( NOTIFICATION_GROUP_KEY )
         .setGroupSummary( true )
         .setStyle( style )
         // You'll want to do this in order to delete the local file if he user swipes away your notification
         .setDeleteIntent( deleteIntent )
         .setAutoCancel( true );
// go directly to NotificationsActivity
summary.setContentIntent( getPendingIntentForNotifications( this, null ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Any reason you prefere doing all these file reading writing instead of using the local db?

Comment: Preference I suppose. Accessing the local file system or SharedPreferences is very easy and I don't have to fuss with doing additional modeling or SQL stuff.